# CodeMirror: Have selection without onscreen keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, codemirror

This sounds a little crazy but what I'm trying to do is a CodeMirror with text cursor/selection but no onscreen iOS keyboard

You may ask: *Whyy?*

Well simple as that ... I wanna build my own onscreen keyboard for iOS touch devices using

```
$codemirror.editor.replaceSelection($key)
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$('textarea').blur()
```

Problem: It doesn't keep the CodeMirror selection